# Java print "?" instead of the thing

Tags: java, string

```
public class javaClass {
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        String row1 = "A____A";
        String row2 = "|・ㅅ・|";
        String row3 = "|っ　ｃ|";
        String row4 = "|　　　|";
        String row5 = "|　　　|";
        String row6 = "U￣￣U";
          
        
        System.out.println(row1);
        System.out.println(row2);
        System.out.println(row3);
        System.out.println(row4);
        System.out.println(row5);
        System.out.println(row6);
    }
}
```

I was trying to print out the drawing when running the code in my windows command prompt, but it print out;

```
A____A
|???|
|???|
|???|
|???|
U??U
```

what I am doing wrong? new to Java

Comment: Running on Windows, aren't we? This is a terminal encoding problem. Java strings are encoded in UTF-16 by default.

Comment: yes is on windows, also how do you change the UTF-16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of your windows command prompt text encoding.

One quick workaround is to switch the font of your command prompt to something that accepts these non-english characters.

eg.

This text:
[image: default]

Becomes this:
[image]

When I change the properties > font from "Consolas" to "MS Gothic"
[image]

[image]